# How do I download steam? What additional software do I need?

Tags: installation, games, steam

When I click download (for steam) I get this message:

> This error could be caused by required additional software packages
>   which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a
>   conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
>   installed at the same time.

I have installed Java, but I don't know what additional software it needs/ requires. When I try to install using terminal it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: steam:i386 : Depends:
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 E: Unable to
correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

First update your Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Steam was added to Ubuntu Software Center, you can install it quite simply through there now. And if there are any missing dependencies they will all be installed before installing steam.

Another way is going to [Steam Powered website](http://store.steampowered.com/) and download they're `.deb` [direct link](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb). Any dependencies required will also be installed.

However if you still encounter problems report back.